# shorthand if else mixing php with javascript not working

Tags: php, javascript

Im attempting to add a `checked` attribute in an input field in javascript that will be outputted as html

Here is my line..

```
var checked = ( <?php echo $original_delivery_date; ?> == json['dates_per_zone'][i]) ? "checked" : "";
```

I have verified that both `json['dates_per_zone'][i]` and `$original_delivery_date` are correct and displaying, but nothing is appearing.

Is that the correct syntax?

My final line is then...

```
html += '<input ' + checked + ' name="delivery_date" value="' + json['dates_per_zone'][i] + '">
```

Comment: And no console log errors?

Comment: "Nothing is appearing" - have you checked the output of that specific line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
var checked = ( '<?php echo $original_delivery_date; ?>' == json['dates_per_zone'][i] ? "checked" : "" );
```

You're missing the quotes around the string that PHP prints.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it, Ill give this correct answer in 10 mins

Answer (score 0):

Use Date as a string:
Like this:

```
var checked = ('<?php echo $original_delivery_date; ?>' == json['dates_per_zone'][i] ? "checked" : "" );
```